# Como verificar qual o nome da aba planilha Excel C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, oledb

Como verificar qual é o nome da "Aba" (Sheet$) da planilha Excel antes de realizar a importação pro `SQL` ?

Meu código até agora:

```
 protected void btnProcessar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\" + FileUpload.FileName;
        this.ImportarArquivoExcel(path);
    }

private void conexaoExcel(string path)
    {
        connectionExcel = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;""", FilePath);
        excelConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionExcel);
    }

    private void conexaoSQL()
    {
        connectionSQL = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionSQL);
    }

 public void ImportarArquivoExcel(string path)
    {
        conexaoExcel(path);

        query = string.Format("Select * FROM [{0}]", "DailySalesDetails$");

        OleDbCommand Ecom = new OleDbCommand(query, excelConn);
        excelConn.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, excelConn);
        excelConn.Close();
        oda.Fill(ds);
        DataTable Exceldt = ds.Tables[0];
        conexaoSQL();
}
```

Comment: O nome do arquivo ou o sheet? Abas

Comment: @GOKUSSJ4 o sheet, como faço pra verificar qual é o nome ?

Comment: Depende do que você está usando para ler o arquivo.  Poste o seu código.

Comment: @GOKUSSJ4 postei amigo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar isso para obter os nomes das abas de um arquivo .xlsx.

Percorra todos os nomes para ler as abas uma a uma.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Rows)
{
   string sht = dr[2].ToString().Replace("'", "");
   OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sht + "]", connection);
}
```

Vejas mais detalhes.
[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358801/how-to-get-sheetname-of-the-uploaded-excel-file-using-c)

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar o método [`GetOleDbSchemaTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.getoledbschematable(v=vs.110).aspx), conforme mencionado [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9274455/1608936).

```
public static List <string> ListSheetInExcel(string filePath) {
    OleDbConnectionStringBuilder sbConnection = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
    sbConnection.DataSource = filePath;
    string strExtendedProperties = string.Empty;

    // Verifica a extensão do arquivo e aplica a Connection String apropriada
    if (Path.GetExtension(filePath).Equals(".xls")) // Excel 97-03
    {
        sbConnection.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
        strExtendedProperties = "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
    } 
    else if (Path.GetExtension(filePath).Equals(".xlsx")) // Excel 2007
    {
        sbConnection.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
        strExtendedProperties = "Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
    }

    sbConnection.Add("Extended Properties", strExtendedProperties);
    List <string> listSheet = new List <string>();

    using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(sbConnection.ToString())) {
        conn.Open();
        System.Data.DataTable dt = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

        foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
            if (row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("$")) {
                listSheet.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }    
    return listSheet;
}
```

Para usar, faça assim:

```
List<string> listSheet = ListSheetInExcel(@"C:\bar\foo.xlsx");

foreach (string sheet in listSheet)
{
     Console.WriteLine(sheet);
}
```

Comment: o Problema é que ele não está conseguindo pegar o nome da Aba, dá um erro louco aqui.

Comment: @AndreeH Qual erro aparece?

Comment: Está retornando vazio o dt. Ele não encontra nenhum nome de Aba.

Comment: @AndreeH Atualizei a resposta, se ainda não funcionar me avise.

Comment: Ainda não, deu problema ao abrir a conexão.